# Is it possible to configure cipher suites used by RabbitMQ Management Plugin?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-management

I have an instance of RabbitMQ [3.7.7-management](https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/blob/4b2b11c59ee65c2a09616b163d4572559a86bb7b/3.7/debian/management/Dockerfile) image running. It has the [rabbitmq-management](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) plugin enabled and configured to use HTTPS as per the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#web-dispatch-config):

```
management.listener.port = 15671
management.listener.ssl = true
management.listener.ssl_opts.cacertfile = /path/to/cacert.pem
management.listener.ssl_opts.certfile = /path/to/cert.pem
management.listener.ssl_opts.keyfile = /path/to/key.pem
management.listener.ssl_opts.fail_if_no_peer_cert = false
management.listener.ssl_opts.versions.1 = tlsv1.2
```

When I evaluate the TLS setup with [testssl.sh](https://github.com/drwetter/testssl.sh) testing tool, a test for **SWEET32** vulnerability fails:

```
Testing vulnerabilities

...
SWEET32 (CVE-2016-2183, CVE-2016-6329)    VULNERABLE, uses 64 bit block ciphers
...
```

[OpenVAS](http://www.openvas.org/) framework also complains:

**Vulnerability Detection Result**

```
'Vulnerable' cipher suites accepted by this service via the TLSv1.2 protocol:
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (SWEET32)
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (SWEET32)
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (SWEET32)
```

**Solution type:** Mitigation

```
The configuration of this services should be changed so that it does not accept the listed cipher suites anymore.
```

Is it possible to configure what cipher suites will be used by the RabbitMQ Management Plugin? For [RabbitMQ it is possible](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#configuring-ciphers), but looking at [rabbitmq_management.schema](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/blob/master/priv/schema/rabbitmq_management.schema) it seems that for the Management Plugin it's impossible. Or is there a different way to fix the vulnerability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the `advanced.config` file to do so. I'm assuming that you have already created `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf` with the settings you show. Create the `/etc/rabbitmq/advanced.config` file with these contents and re-start RabbitMQ:

```
[
    {rabbitmq_management, [
        {listener, [
            {ssl_opts, [
                {ciphers, [
                    %% CIPHERS GO HERE
                ]}
            ]}
        ]}
    ]}
].
```

The setting should be merged into what is specified in `rabbitmq.conf`. You can check the generated config files in `/var/lib/rabbitmq/...`